# Is there any possibility to add fields inside the fields of a Model

Tags: django, django-models

Assume I have a model named `MyModel` and I have a Field Named `field` Now I want to add three more fields inside the prescription like one `field_a` , `field_b` and `field_c` .

Does Django Allow that in any way or we have to make another model for this purpose and then link with Foreign Key to MyModel?

Comment: Why not add these to `MyModel` directly?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to not use a Foreign key to another model?

Answer (score 1):

Well I think it is an idea that could lead to some really hard to maintain code and should be well thought through.

That aside If you have a look at:
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html
It's a special field meant for cms applications that uses json in the field to model dynamic fields and validations for it.

Also if you run postgres this might help. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield